# How to define two classes for one DB table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one table `np_user_dtls` with 4 fields in sql server

```
user_name
user_last_name
arabic_name
nationality
```

In mvc i created a model class as below

```
 public partial class np_user_dtls
    {


        [Display(Name = "First Name*")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
        public string user_name { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "last name is required.")]
        public string user_last_name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "arabic name is required.")]
        public string arabic_name { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "nationality is required.")]
        public string nationality { get; set; }
   }
```

and in context model i define the relationship between model class and db table as follow

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<****.Models.np_user_dtls> np_user__dtls { get; set; }
```

now i need an another class in which arabic name is not mandatory

so i create a model like below

```
 public partial class np_user_dtls_1
        {


            [Display(Name = "First Name*")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
            public string user_name { get; set; }


            [Required(ErrorMessage = "last name is required.")]
            public string user_last_name { get; set; }


           [Required(ErrorMessage = "nationality is required.")]
            public string nationality { get; set; }
       }
```

but when i create an entry for this in db context like below

```
   public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<****.Models.np_user_dtls_1> np_user__dtls { get; set; }
```

its giving me an error

> The type ****.Models.***** already contains a definition for
>   np_user__dtls

is it not possible to define multiple model for a single table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set one entity model for one table. then you can bind different view model with your entity model.
entity class.

```
public partial class np_user_dtls
{

    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string user_last_name { get; set; }
    public string arabic_name { get; set; }
    public string nationality { get; set; }
}
```

you can use this class for database table.

```
public partial class np_user_dtls_response1
{


    [Display(Name = "First Name*")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    public string user_name { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "last name is required.")]
    public string user_last_name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "arabic name is required.")]
    public string arabic_name { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "nationality is required.")]
    public string nationality { get; set; }
}
```

you can use this class as view model. accept request by this class. then map this class np_user_dtls and save information in db.

later you can use another view model class such as

```
public partial class np_user_dtls_response2
    {


        [Display(Name = "First Name*")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
        public string user_name { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "last name is required.")]
        public string user_last_name { get; set; }


       [Required(ErrorMessage = "nationality is required.")]
        public string nationality { get; set; }
   }
```

bind this class again with class np_user_dtls and save information in db. In this you can use two kind of validation in application level save data in database. Previously you can set validation database level. thats why you cant set two class

Comment: because of [Required] in arabic_name if i save data to the table from second view it will give entiry error

Comment: you can set arabic_name not required in the table. For one view model you can set arabic_name required and another viewmodel set arabic_name non required. Then both can bind with same enitity model.